# 1D barcode scanning to web app using handheld scanner

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I am looking for some advice on scanning barcodes into our web app via post/get etc.

We would be looking to use some kind of handheld scanner with a mobile computer built in (windows or linux etc.) and wifi.

I have done some reading and found a few articles on using an iPhone but cant find anything explicitly using a standalone scanner, so would like to get some advice before we buy one and give it a go.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly a programming question, yes, we did that.  We use a Honeywell Dolphin 75e device with Android, it has a superb scanning engine, to just do this:  Scan data and transmit it via HTTPS.

Comment: I would like to know how to set & code similar web app, but hard to find out some working solution. A solution with scan with web cam isn't so easy to implement (focus at image, distance from cam, shaking of hand...).